# Azure - Custom Domain with Oauth Redirect Setup

Tags: python, azure, https, oauth, dns

I prefer reading questions when they are bullet pointed to explain the setup.

- I have an azure hosted python/Flask webapp. E.G. http://example.azurewebsites.net
- Have setup the custom domain which is https. E.G https://mycustom.com
- Website work fine (occasionally pages are getting redirected back from mycustom.com/login, to example.azure.net/login - which I don't know how to fix).
- Now, I would like to use Oauth for a Facebook login, but the login page which goes to the Facebook authentication login page is using http://example.azurewebsite.net which Facebook no longer allows.

Is this an issue with my Azure settings or domain settings (godaddy) or something else?

I been searching for sometime but cannot find a solution,

Any insights appreciated,

Comment: `occasionally pages are getting redirected back from mycustom.com/login, to example.azure.net/login `, For this, could you provide more details, it sounds like a temporary issue?

Comment: I can't replicate that error everytime, however, my main issue (and this question) is when a user goes to www.karlduckett.com/facebook_login the address bar indicates that the user came from an azurewebsite.net address - (which is http and not able to be used as oauth by Facebook). 

Hope that makes sense. I'm still learning and all of this is just for my own experience. But any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to access the custom domain websites with https? So, do you upload an SSL cert for that website?

Comment: Do you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-facebook) to use Facebook for authentication in your app? and see configure ssl cert from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate

Comment: I'm not using Azure's authentication as I the user to be able to select which Oauth they would like to use (Facebook, Github etc). The Custom Domain does have a SSL cert already. The code works on Loclhost - but not when uploaded due to the redirct URI defaulting back to the http .azurewebsite.net.

Comment: Oh, after a bit more trouble shooting a found some more info:
If the user goes to the initial homepage (www.karlduckett.com) first, then navigates to www.karlduckett.com/facebook_login the redirect isn't defaulted back. Only if the user types www.karlduckett.com/facebook_login direct is it redirected.... strange, but interesting...

Comment: It looks like something wrong in your code.